# Any Idea what this connector might be?

Tags: electrical, heating, generator, steam

Any idea what the pictured connector might be and how it might be replaced/connected again?
It is part of a steam generator, for a steam shower, providing power to the heating element, I believe. It has an identical one on a black wire that was worn through completely. Just hoping it is a common part.
[image]

Here are some more pics to show the gory details.
[image]

You can see the where they disconnected here.
[image]

And if you look past the red wires you can see where the other side is still nice and tidy. (How these should look)
[image]

Comment: Is the face of the orange side flat, or is it a receptacle? Do you have a model number for the steam generator? You may be able to find a schematic.

Comment: It looks like simple ring terminal like this one, the other side is just a bolt. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Ditto @GaTechThomas.  It ooks like a heating element might fit into the orange side, maybe?

Comment: @GaTechThomas I found several schematics, thanks for the suggestion. The model is a Steamist SM-11 Some of them mention fuses on these lines, could these be those?
I added some more photos.

Comment: That looks like a power wiring terminal that has broken off from the heating coil

Comment: @Enjabain see my answer where I provided more details - your heating element is probably inclusive of the ceramic heat protector. That means you would need the entire heating element to fix it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Ceramic Insulator for heat protection - the wires go to the heating element.

**EDIT 5-8-2017**

As per Ed Beals comment (Thanks for the FYI) - I will make some explanation here .

Heating elements are exactly that they heat up as the electricity flows through them, they have different ratings of wattage consequently also heat output, How hot they get. Because of this there needs to be a method of protecting the wiring of the circuit from the transference of this heat.

The heat transferring via the wire into the insulation can melt or make brittle the insulation and thereby create a potential fire hazard and or electrocution hazard. Ceramic Insulators are used to dissipate the heat and prevent this transference that would cause the insulation of the wires to melt or become brittle.

Over time the heat will cause these ceramic insulators to break  down - constant heating and cooling causing them to crack and become brittle and break. You need to use them in the replacement of your part and in connecting the wires to the heating element - unless you would like to risk the lives of the  occupants of the home to fire.

I should also add that sometimes the heating element itself has this component - and therefore a new element would need to be purchased.

Comment: I believe your answer is correct but some additional explanation would make your answer better.

Comment: @EdBeal - updated with info - looking closer at his picture it looks like his heating element and definitely broken. I also edited that the part he needs to order is probably the whole heating element.

Comment: I agree and think you have the right idea on how to answer a question. Keep up the good work.